# Keyword search passing in Urls to return results in Fast Search 2010

Tags: search, fast-search, url

I am performing a keyword search, passing in 3 urls which are different places within the site. The idea is to search where (urls = url1 or urls = url2 or urls = url3).

I've got a managed property in search called urls, however it only works if I search for one url. If I add another urls in the "or" clause it only brings back the last URL in the query.

```
urls:https://site1/sites/Blog/Lists/Posts/ViewPost.aspx?ID=2
```

Will bring back result. But

```
urls:https://site1/sites/Blog/Lists/Posts/ViewPost.aspx?ID=2 OR urls:https://site2/sites/Blog/Lists/Posts/ViewPost.aspx?ID=5
```

will only bring back the last link.

Does anyone know how to do a search using the URLs?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself. Use "Path" in search query.

```
Path:"https://site1/sites/Blog/Lists/Posts/ViewPost.aspx?ID=2" OR Path:"https://site2/sites/sBlog/Lists/Posts/ViewPost.aspx?ID=5"
```